# Working with an One-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy efficient way

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I am a beginner SQL user.

I have one DB with three tables, the table Person and the tables Hotel and Apartment. Each Person has just one relationship to one Hotel or Apartment but each Hotel or Apartment can have one or more persons assigned to them.

Having the following schema:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    person_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String, nullable=False) 

class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hotel'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    hotel_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hotel_address = Column(String)

    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), nullable=False)
    person = relationship("Person", backref=backref("hotel", uselist=False))

class Apartment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apartment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    apartment_address = Column(String, nullable=False)

    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), nullable=False)
    person = relationship("Person", backref=backref("apartment", uselist=False))
```

Or this one, where each hotel and apartment would have an unique key,and working with filtering the new "key" column:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    person_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String, nullable=False) 
    key = Column(String, nullable=False) 

class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hotel'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    hotel_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hotel_address = Column(String)
    key = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Apartment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apartment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    apartment_address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    key = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Are the columns "id" unnecessary in the Hotel and Apartment tables when having a unique key?

The second question, is about this column in Person table:

```
status = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

I would like to have the status column just one of the values in (hotel, apartment), that would tell where exactly look for the relationship, in hotel or apartment table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you have `person_id` columns in `Hotel` and `Apartment` tables, which means you will have separate record in `Hotel` or `Apartment` tables for each person, which doesn't seem like what you intend to do. So the foreign key should be moved to `Person` table.
So the next problem is to use one foreign key to both tables, so that you wouldn't have to do tedious checks (like check if hotel_id is set when you set apartment_id). This can be done using SqlAlchemy's `polymorphic_identity`. You can read about it [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/inheritance.html). Here's what your model structure should look like in this case:

```
class Person(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'person'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        person_name = Column(String, nullable=False)

        accommodation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accommodation.id"))
        accommodation = relationship("Accommodation", backref="people")


class Accommodation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accommodation'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'accommodation',
        # polymorphic_on determines the field that will have values like 'hotel' and 'apartment' depending on the table
        'polymorphic_on': 'accommodation_type'
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    accommodation_type = Column(String(32))
    address = Column(String)


class Hotel(Accommodation):
        __tablename__ = 'hotel'
        __mapper_args__ = {
            # all the records in this table will have accommodation_type = 'hotel'
            'polymorphic_identity': 'hotel'
        }

        id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accommodation.id'), primary_key=True)
        hotel_name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Apartment(Accommodation):
        __tablename__ = 'apartment'
        __mapper_args__ = {
            # all the records in this table will have accommodation_type = 'apartment'
            'polymorphic_identity': 'apartment'
        }

        id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accommodation.id'), primary_key=True)
```

This way, you have base model `Accommodation`, and it's `id` is linked to `id` columns in tables `Hotel` and `Appartment`, which contain only the fields specific to them. `person.accommodation` will return either hotel or apartment, depending on the actual value, and all the attributes of the parent and child table will be available. This way you can be sure that one person won't be linked both to hotel and apartment. You can check the type of accommodation the person is linke to by checking `person.accommodation.accommodation_type`.

Comment: Thanks, it just what i needed. But still have one question I couldnt find in google. How to transform an Hotel into an Apartment? I mean, keeping the id and address and update the accommodation_type. I tried with: accommodation_type = "apartment" but didnt create the record in Apartment and delete in Hotel tables.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do that, you'll have to delete the old record and insert the new one manually. But why would you need to transform Hotel into Apartment? This may strongly hint to some flaw in logic of your app.

Comment: If you're sure that's what you need, you could write a class method in Accommodation class that will take the new type and the instance that needs to be changed as parameters and do all the work: insert the new record with all the necessary values, update the accommodation_id in Person table and then delete the old one. But once again, it doesn't look very pretty, so think again if this is what you need, and if this architecture fits your task.